# How to make physics of motion on an inclined surface

Tags: javascript, phaser

There is the following platform:

[image]

And a coin above it:

[image]

And the following code using arcade physics:

```
gravity: { y: 100, x: 10 }, - in config

function preload ()
{
this.load.image('platform', 'assets/platform.png');
this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
}

function create ()
{
platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

platforms.create(400, 568, 'platform');

player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'star');

player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
}
```

The code is approximate, a coin above the platform, sprites in png format. But the coin falls and does not roll, but moves horizontally, after which it falls again. How to make it "roll"?

UPD: Will it help me? https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-examples/blob/master/examples/arcade%20physics/circle%20body.js
And how to be with the platform?

Comment: In the image, you can see the front and right side of the coin. If you just rotate the image, you'll see the front and bottom. Perspective will be messed up. You would need to animate it somehow

Comment: But how will animation help physics?